# cannot use sql temporary tables in VBA (cannot drop table)

Tags: sql, vba

how can I change my vba code so that it will manage to run temporary table in sql query
this is my VBA code (stored procedure contains temp table)

```
Sub a()
Dim connection As ADODB.connection
Dim recordset As ADODB.recordset
Dim command As ADODB.command
Dim strProcName As String 'Stored Procedure name
Dim strConn As String ' connection string.
Dim selectedVal As String


Set connection = New ADODB.connection
Set recordset = New ADODB.recordset
Set command = New ADODB.command
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=true;Data source =1.1.2.7\B;User ID = sa; password=a;Initial catalog=A"
connection.ConnectionString = strConn
connection.Open

command.ActiveConnection = connection
command.CommandText = "pLOAN_LIST"
command.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
command.Parameters.Refresh
'command.Parameters(1).Value = "3"

Set recordset = command.Execute()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset recordset

recordset.Close
Set recordset = Nothing

connection.Close
Set connection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you asking for? It's unclear

Answer (score 0):

Really, it's not your VBA code that generates or uses the temporary table - it's your stored procedure.  Likewise, it's your stored procedure that returns the temporary table.

For instance, if you want to return the value sets from a stored procedure you'd simply select it as the last output...

```sql
SELECT 
    myfield1, 
    myfield2, 
    myfield_n
FROM 
    @mydefinedtable 
WHERE 
    condition = requirement
```

So, perhaps you need to identify, first, what your stored procedure actually does.

Perhaps [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/259-creating-in-memory-tables-in-sql-for-joining-and-sumarizing.htm) can detail this better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dropping the table, why don't you just delete all the data. You cannot drop a table that is in use. This solution might not work for you, but if you drop the data inside the table but keep the table, it's basically the same effect.